# How to create multiple SSID

Tags: wireless-networking

I have one dlink wifi router, 10 employees, One Active Directory. Desktop employees are using LAN but I need all the wifi users should use their wifi by using their emp id and password.

How to do settings in wifi router and AD

Comment: Look up using a RADIUS server. This allows integrating a wireless network controller with an Active Directory server. You can use an old PC with, say, FreeRADIUS installed but it needs configuring and there's no guarantee your bog-standard wireless router can be configured to talk to a RADIUS server... You may need to upgrade and it may not be very cheap.

Comment: What does this have to do with having multiple SSIDs?  Having multiple SSIDs wouldn't accomplish your goal.

Comment: SSID stands for **S**ervice **S**et **ID**entifier. Simply put, it is the name of the WiFi. Is has no control of how the users log in using AD credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Ramhound said, multiple ESSID wont solve your problems. You will need to create a captive portal or *WPA Enterprise* based network.

In both the cases you will need a Freeradius server which will verify users from you Active Directory. Your router might be able to do WPA Enterprise but it will definitely not do Captive portal, I would suggest you flash your router with OpenWRT first and then setup your Freeradius server.